# JavaScript eventListener is not a function error

Tags: javascript, html

I have established my buttons:

```
    <div class="calculator">

    <div class="display">
        <p class="numberContent"></p>
    </div>


<div class="operations">
    <button class= 'btn add'>+</button>
    <button class= 'btn subtract'>-</button>
    <button class= 'btn multiply'>x</button>
    <button class= 'btn divide'>&divide</button>
    <button class= 'btn clear'>CLEAR</button>
</div>
and onwards...
```

In Javascript I would like to be able to add event listeners to all the buttons so I can write the code for the functionality.

I attempted this test but  it throws an error: Uncaught TypeError: btn.addEventListener is not a function

```
let btn= document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    alert('clicked')
})
```

Can someone tell me why I cant add an event listener to all of the members of the class selector.
Thanks

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList of all matches, not a single element. To return a single element use `.querySelector()` which will return the first matched element.

Comment: I want to select all elements with a class of btn, not  just a single element. When I use .querySelector() it just throws: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Then you need to loop through the returned list, or attach the listener to the parent and use `event.target` to access specific buttons.

Comment: There is no element with the class `btn` in your HTML.

Comment: And there's that...

Comment: ```class= 'btn.add'>``` is not a applied the btn class its include the word , will be like ```class= 'btn btn.add'>```

Comment: Trying to put periods in a class name is just asking for selector issues.

Comment: I agree with pointing it out, but seems it may be inadvertent and OP meant `class='btn add'`

Answer (score 1):

As it was already mentioned by others, `querySelectorAll()` gives you a `NodeList`. You could create an array from this `NodeList` and then iterate over it.

```
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const btnArray = Array.from(btn);
btnArray.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert('clicked');
  });
});
```

To make it work, please make sure that your HTML elements have the classes assigned correctly.

```
<div class="operations">
    <button class= 'btn add'>+</button>
    <button class= 'btn subtract'>-</button>
    <button class= 'btn multiply'>x</button>
    <button class= 'btn divide'>&divide</button>
    <button class= 'btn clear'>CLEAR</button>
</div>
```